# wave equation solution

Tags: waves

Since solution of a heat flow problem means to determine the temperature distribution in a medium.Likewise i want to know that what the solution of wave equation depict?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of the wave equation describe the wave's amplitude at different points, and depending on the context, that amplitude can mean different things. For a standing wave on a string, the solution to the wave equation gives the displacement of the string at a given point. For a wave on water, it may be the height of the wave. It is completely contextual.